# Solve for x, $2=e^{3x}-x$?

Tags: lambert-w

The Lambert W function should be able to help me with this but for the life of me I can't figure out how.

Comment: Wolfram alpha knows [how](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve[2%3De^%283x%29-x%2C+x])

Comment: Why do you think the Lambert W function might help you?

Comment: As Ben Longo stated, Wolfram alpha knew how, which is what lead me to research the lambert W, but I couldn't get wolfram alpha to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{-3x}(x+2)=1\\e^{-3x-6}(-3x-6)=e^{-6}(-3)$$

Comment: That explains everything.  *facepalm*